# Using and changing of URI Schemes within a Java Application on MacOS

Tags: java, macos, uri, url-scheme, info.plist

i need a solution for the following problem.

I write a java application (in Netbeans).
This java application should also start by using a URI-Scheme, like myapp://someParameter, on MacOSX. In my case 10.10 Yosemite.

But for the applications itself, it should be possible to add additional uri schemes to itself on runtime. More precisely, the user can add new additional uri schemes by using this application.

How can i do this? After my research, i should create an app package (myapp.app) with my java programm. The approach is, to change the info.plist file in this package. But is this possible? The problem here is the Signature of the app bundle, right?

Know someone a solution for this problem? Has MacOS not a central point to set such uri scheme for application, like in windows or linux?

Thanks for your help.